# Search tab of chm file created from a single html file

Tags: html, search, chm, asciidoctor, html-help-workshop

I have created a `chm` file from a single `html` file generated using `asciidoctor`. The contents and index of `chm` file points to specific sections of the same `html` file. However, when I use the `search tab`, even though all the search hits are highlighted in the file, the `'Select topic o display'` part lists only the name of the `html` file itself. Is there a way by which I can display the section names from the html file in the search tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topics are better to be separated into smaller units and individual HTML files when building a CHM help file.

In this way, the assignment to the Table of Contents (TOC) is easier to make. The result of a search is then clear and I'd recommend this method.

Of course, you can jump to anchor tag from TOC (see below). When you perform a search, the results list is a bunch of items with titles lifted from each documents `<title>` tag. As far as I tested you cannot change the title in the seach result list.

I remember if binary TOC is enabled one may see titles that do not seem to correspond with the associated Topics. What happens is for a binary TOC the topic title is lifted from a TOC item label instead of the documents `<title>` tag. I suspect that this is a HH 1.x Collections feature.

A *.hhc (TOC) file example:

```
     <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
           <param name="Name" value="How to use shortcut links">
           <param name="Local" value="HTMLHelp_Examples/shortcut_link.htm">
         </OBJECT>
     <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
           <param name="Name" value="How to jump to a anchor">
           <param name="Local" value="HTMLHelp_Examples/Jump_to_anchor.htm#AnchorSample">
         </OBJECT>
```

As mentioned above I'd recommend to split the topics.

Comment: Thank you. But I am creating mu html file using `asciidoctor` tool and it generates only a single html file. So splitting into individual files is not possible as of now. So anchor tag cannot be used for search results?

Comment: I'll go into this later and I'll give the binary TOC a try. You are using HTML Help Workshop only for creating the CHM file?

Comment: After testing it seems to me there is no chance for another title in the search list when using anchor tags.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your time.. It seems I have to remove the search option from my chm file :(

Comment: Only a idea and not tested is making a workflow from asciidoctor => DocBook => CHM. I remember DocBook has some XSLT for creating CHM  (not easy to do). This makes only sense in your question context when the step asciidoctor => DocBook  makes the topic split for you I mentioned above and the next step to CHM works with this.